# Placing the legend on a BarChart

Tags: plotting, legending, charts

I would like to have the label on the plot rather than on the side.

```
BarChart[
  {{0, 12.2`, 45.2`, 16.3`, 26.1`}, {0.1`, 13.7`, 49.7`, 16.7`, 27.9`}}\[Transpose], 
  PlotRange -> {{0, 12}, {0, 70}}, 
  Frame -> True, 
  PlotRangePadding -> {{0.5, 0.5}, 0}, 
  PlotRangeClipping -> True, 
  GridLines -> {None, Range[0, 10000, 5]},
  BarSpacing -> {-0.5, 1}, 
  ChartLegends -> {Style["a", 23], Style["b", 23]},
  ImageSize -> 800]
```

any idea?

Comment: `ChartLegends -> Placed[{Style["a", 23], Style["b", 23]}, {Right, Top}]`?

Comment: yes! and how do I change the background color and frame it?

Comment: Look up `SwatchLegend` and its options for the details

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use

```
ChartLegends -> 
 Placed[SwatchLegend[Automatic, {Style["a", 23], Style["b", 23]}, 
   LegendFunction -> (Framed[#, Background -> LightGray, 
       RoundingRadius -> 5] &), LegendMarkerSize -> 25], {.9, .85}]
```

as suggested by Szabolcs in comments.

An alternative method is to use the option [`LegendAppearance`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LegendAppearance.html) to inject legend options:

```
bc = BarChart[{{0, 12.2`, 45.2`, 16.3`, 26.1`}, {0.1`, 13.7`, 49.7`, 
     16.7`, 27.9`}}\[Transpose], PlotRange -> {{0, 12}, {0, 70}}, 
  Frame -> True, PlotRangePadding -> {{0.5, 0.5}, 0}, 
  PlotRangeClipping -> True, GridLines -> {None, Range[0, 10000, 5]}, 
  BarSpacing -> {-0.5, 1}, 
  LegendAppearance -> 
    {LegendFunction -> (Framed[#, Background -> LightGray, RoundingRadius -> 5] &), 
    LegendMarkerSize -> 25}, 
  ChartLegends -> Placed[{Style["a", 23], Style["b", 23]}, {.9, .85}],
   ImageSize -> 800]
```

[image]

A simple post-processing to interactively control legend position:

```
DynamicModule[{pt = {11, 60}}, 
 Show[bc[[1]], Epilog -> Dynamic@{Locator[Dynamic[pt], bc[[2, 1, 1]]]}]]
```

[image]